# Swift How to remove UITableView header that appears on scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I scroll on my `UITableView`, an empty header appears at the top of the view that prevents the user to see some information properly as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I remove this?

Comment: It's a navigation bar. Just search how to hide navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a `UINavigationBar` that you're seeing. Try this in your UIViewController to hide the navigation bar:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```

If the navigation bar is used in previous view controllers in your navigation stack, make sure to make it visible there again.